# The "idiomatics" of a pattern match in Scala

Tags: scala

I've been trying to pick up Scala for a while and I absolutely love it, but a lot of the time when I use it I'm constantly afraid I'm not using it "correctly", even when, like in this case, it produces the correct result.
Please consider this code:

```
val list1 = List(0, 0, 0, 1)
val list2 = List(0, 0, 0, 2)
val list3 = List(0, 0, 1, 2)
val list4 = List(0, 0, 0, 0)

def numCheck(listToCheck: List[Int]): String = {
  listToCheck match {
    case l if l.contains(1) => "Contains a one"
    case l if l.contains(2) => "Contains a two, but no ones"
    case _ => "Contains no ones or twos"
  }
}

println(numCheck(list1))
println(numCheck(list2))
println(numCheck(list3))
println(numCheck(list4))
```

The output is:

```
Contains a one
Contains a two, but no ones
Contains a one
Contains no ones or twos
```

This is a solution to a simplified version of a problem that I solved using the exact same approach you can see, and output is correct.

What I was wondering is whether a pattern match was even the right way to go here? And if it is, can it be simplified further? Does Scala have a language feature better suited for solving this problem?
The reason I'm doubting myself is because my solution does not look like any of the many examples I've seen while learning the language -I've put almost all the logic is in the guards.

I would also love it if somebody could point me in the direction some learning resources that focus on pattern matching.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've written looks okay to me, although it is slightly awkward that you've introduced this new identifier `l` that is redundant to `listToCheck` since they're always the same. I'd avoid doing that.

Here are some other choices. I'm not sure any one of them is particularly idiomatic.

- Define `numCheck` as a function instead of a method. I think this is the cleanest way to express this code, but if you *need* it to be a method then you might not be able to get away with it.

  ```
  val numCheck: List[Int] => String = {
    case l if l.contains(1) => "Contains a one"
    case l if l.contains(2) => "Contains a two, but no ones"
    case _                  => "Contains no ones or twos"
  }
  ```
- Use an *if-else* chain. This is probably the "simplest" approach, but it has the downside of being a bit ugly because the cases don't line up very nicely.

  ```
  def numCheck(l: List[Int]): String =
         if (l.contains(1)) "Contains a one"
    else if (l.contains(2)) "Contains a two, but no ones"
    else                    "Contains no ones or twos"
  ```
- Match on a dummy value `() match { ...` and throw it away (`case _ ...`) in every case. This feels a bit abusive of the `match` syntax, but it does give you a nice uniformity among the cases.

  ```
  def numCheck(listToCheck: List[Int]): String = () match {
    case _ if listToCheck.contains(1) => "Contains a one"
    case _ if listToCheck.contains(2) => "Contains a two, but no ones"
    case _                            => "Contains no ones or twos"
  }
  ```

---

Digression:

You didn't ask, but *just for irrelevant curiosity's sake*, the equivalent Haskell would look like

- This:

  ```
  numCheck list | elem 1 list = "Contains a one"
                | elem 2 list = "Contains a two, but no ones"
                | otherwise   = "Contains no ones or twos"
  ```
- Or this:

  ```
  numCheck list | elem 1 list = "Contains a one"
  numCheck list | elem 2 list = "Contains a two, but no ones"
  numCheck _                  = "Contains no ones or twos"
  ```
- Or using the *multi-way if* extension:

  ```
  :set -XMultiWayIf

  numCheck list = if | elem 1 list -> "Contains a one"
                     | elem 2 list -> "Contains a two, but no ones"
                     | otherwise   -> "Contains no ones or twos"
  ```

Usage:

```
sequence $ putStrLn . numCheck <$> [[0,0,0,1], [0,0,0,2], [0,0,1,2], [0,0,0,0]]
```

Comment: Interesting! So when defining numCheck as a function the match is implicit? I find that when I try to use the same approach on a method it doesn't compile("Cannot resolve symbol contains"). This is exactly the kind of pointers I'm looking for, thank you!

Comment: Without the `match` keyword, a pattern match expression has the type `Function` or `PartialFunction`, depending on the context. In the above example the context demands `Function[List[Int], String]`, so that's what it becomes. Yes, you could think of it as desugaring `{ case ... }` to `x => x match { case ... }`. I don't remember whether it's defined exactly that way.

Comment: I tihnk people avoid `if`/`else` chains too much sometimes. For me, this is the [say what you mean, simply and directly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Programming_Style) variant here.